# Create two different location paths on a single button (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create two different location paths for one single button. I have one view that is being used in different parts of the application and when the user clicks cancel it should take them back to last view. However, in my controller I have:

```
$scope.cancel = function(){
    $location.path('app/properties'); 
};
```

So no matter where they are in the application it will always take them back to app/properties.

Is there a way I can work around this problem without creating a separate view and controller? For example I need the one of the cancel buttons to go here:

```
$scope.cancel = function(){
    $location.path('app/properties'); 
};
```

and I need another cancel button to here:

```
$scope.cancel = function(){
    $location.path('app/inspections'); 
};
```

But they would be in the same controller and view. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it seat within a directive?

Comment: No, it is not currently in a directive. It is in a controller. Do you think that would be easier?

Comment: It all depends on how you are using this controller, but usually it is a good idea to have a single customizable directive for a small functionality  like this. How come you are reusing same controller for two different things?

Answer (score 0):

Try with simple condition:

```
$scope.cancel = function(condition){
 if(condition === 1){
    $location.path('app/properties');
 }else if(condition === 2){ 
    $location.path('app/inspections');
 }
};
```